# How to Upgrade Unlocked/Jailbroken Iphone 3g to 3.0 Software

Tags: iphone

I have an Iphone 3G that has been unlocked using the Cydia installer. I'm also under the impression that upgrading the firmware of my Iphone (at this point) will 'relock' my phone, basically restoring it to factory settings.

My question is: Does anyone know how to upgrade to 3.0 OS while avoiding the restore? Again, I believe Cydia was used to unlock the phone in the first place.

Thanks Folks.

Comment: did my answer fix your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot upgrade without restoring. You will have to re-jailbreak if you upgrade. But rejailbreaking is extremely simple. And you can nearly automate the process of having your jailbroken apps restored to your upgraded phone..:

1. Download Rock App (jailbroken) through Cydia.
2. Register and save a backup list
3. Upgrade your phone via Itunes to 3.x.x
4. Jailbreak with [Blackra1n](http://www.blackra1n.com/)
5. Install Rock with the Blackra1n app.
6. Go into Rock and restore all of your apps.

cheers